# LiteDB database doesn't persist between sessions

Tags: c#, .net, persistence, litedb

I've been using liteDB to store some values. However i tried setting up a 2. db to save some different values and those ones do not persist between application restarts. Embeds does persist. General settings do not. I have no idea why this happens or where the difference is. During the session i can save and read the values without any problems but after restarting values are lost.

```
string botToken = "SOMEVALUE";
DBhelper.addGeneralSetting(botToken);
```

```
public DataBaseHelper()
{
    db = new LiteDatabase(@"Embeds.db");
    // Get collection
    collection = db.GetCollection<ServerEmbed>("Embeds");
    // Create unique index in MessageID field
    collection.EnsureIndex(x => x.MessageID, true);
    settingDb = new LiteDatabase(@"GeneralSettings.db");
    generalSettings = settingDb.GetCollection<GeneralSetting>("GeneralSettings");
    generalSettings.EnsureIndex(x=> x.Setting, true);
}
public void addToDatabase(ServerEmbed embed)
{
    collection.Insert(embed);
}
public void addGeneralSetting(GeneralSetting setting)
{
    generalSettings.Insert(setting);
}
```

```
public class GeneralSetting
{
    [BsonField("Setting")]
    public string Setting { get; set; }
    [BsonField("Value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public GeneralSetting(string setting, object value)
    {
        Setting = setting;
        Value = value;
    }
    public GeneralSetting() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Key: {Setting} + Value {Value.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you gracefully dispose the dbs on Application Exit?

Comment: no. Since it's a commandline application for now i'm not entirely sure how to run code when it's supposed to close tbh.

Comment: ok did a bit of research and added

```
 db.Dispose();
 settingDb.Dispose();
```
For
```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
``` but that doesn't seem to change anything unless thats not what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But it doesn't do the trick ... and you sure don't get _any_ exceptions or anything?

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions no. It's being added to the database successfully as retrieving it works fine while the application is running, just doesn't get saved for some reason.

Comment: @Jods Just to be sure. Have you checked that ``OnProcessExit`` is called or executed?

Comment: @h.m.i.13
it doesn't seem to be executing can't rly tell why though this is the code

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);

   void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DBhelper.exit();
      Console.WriteLine("I'm out of here");
  }

DbHelper.Exit() = db.Dispose(); settingDb.Dispose();

Comment: @Jods can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675024 be helpful?

Comment: @h.m.i.13 that explains why it's not being called yeah since it's a commandline application rude exits are the only things that can happen :D